# Serve static files from google-cloud-storage through express middleware

Tags: node.js, express, google-app-engine, google-cloud-storage

I have an express app hosted on google `AppEngine` which uses the express static middleware. I'd like to store the static files on `google-cloud-storage`, and to be able to switch from regular filesystem to `google-cloud-storage` without too much modification.

I was thinking of writing a middleware:

- using the [Google Cloud client library for Node.js](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/google-cloud-node), something like [Express caching Image stream from Google Cloud Storage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32976838/express-caching-image-stream-from-google-cloud-storage)) ;
- or acting as a proxy (mapping pathnames to raw `google-cloud-storage` urls).

Is there an easier/cleaner way to do that ?

Comment: could you proxy successfully? im getting an `NoSuchBucket` error if I try and go through a proxy

Answer (score 5):

I made this work using http-proxy-middleware. Essentially, since GCS files can be accessed via http protocol, this is all we need.

Ideally, the files could be served directly out of GCS itself, by making the bucket public and making its URL like `https://storage.googleapis.com/<bucket-name>/file`. But my requirement was the file needed to be served from the *same domain* as my app, but the files were not part of the app itself (they are generated separately). So, I had to implement it as a proxy.

```
import proxy from 'http-proxy-middleware';
...

app.use('/public', proxy({
  target: `https://storage.googleapis.com/${process.env.GOOGLE_CLOUD_PROJECT}.appspot.com`,
  changeOrigin: true,
}));
```

Note that the bucket based on the project ID is automatically created by GAE, but it needs to be given public access. This can be done by

```
gsutil defacl set public-read gs://${GOOGLE_CLOUD_PROJECT}.appspot.com
```

After setting up the proxy, all requests to https://example.com/public/* will served from the bucket `<GOOGLE_CLOUD_PROJECT>.appspot.com/public/*`.

Answer (score 4):

I require the same and came across the example used on [google cloud node](https://github.com/googleapis/google-cloud-node) or see [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32976838/express-caching-image-stream-from-google-cloud-storage) in another question

Pipe the readstream of the file-contents to your response.
Set the file-name and content-type

```js
// Add headers to describe file
let headers = {
   'Content-disposition': 'attachment; filename="' + 'giraffe.jpg' + '"',
   'Content-Type': 'image/png'
};

// Streams are supported for reading files.
let remoteReadStream = bucket.file('giraffe.jpg').createReadStream();

// Set the response code & headers and pipe content to response
res.status(200).set(headers);
remoteReadStream.pipe(res);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could [configure a GCS bucket to host a static website](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/hosting-static-website) and then use [an existing](https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-http-proxy) express middleware to proxy requests to that bucket.

Comment: Thank you, that's what I mentioned as a second option in my question, but I hoped there was something more straightforward.

Answer (score -1):

You might also be able to use an s3 express middleware like [s3-proxy](https://www.npmjs.com/package/s3-proxy). By following the 'simple' migration steps to move an [s3 client application to google cloud storage](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/migrating#migration-simple) you should be able to derive the necessary config parameters for the middleware. The key step will be generating some 'access' and 'secret' [developer keys](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/migrating#keys).